# Babel throwing Cannot read property 'bindings' of null error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, babeljs

We have recently upgraded our Meteor+React application to use Meteor 1.7. Previously, it was Meteor 1.6. We are using Babel for transpilation. As the migration documentation suggests, we have upgraded Babel to 7. And for Babel 7, it is suggested that we used `babel-preset-env` instead of `babel-preset-es2015`. Since, we made all these changes, we are getting the following error when we do `meteor run`.

While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):

```
 C:\Users\kashif.nazar\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\ecmascript\0.11.1\plugin.compile-ecmascript.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\scope\index.js:869:13:
   Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
```

Please note that `meteor npm install` runs fine.

The dependencies in the `package.json` file are as below.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babyparse": "^0.4.6",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bufferutil": "^3.0.0",
    "co": "^4.6.0",
    "date-math": "0.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "echarts": "^3.4.0",
    "echarts-for-react": "^1.1.6",
    "exceljs": "^0.5.0",
    "extract-params": "^3.0.2",
    "fibers": "^1.0.15",
    "glamor": "^2.20.40",
    "halogen": "^0.2.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "indexof": "0.0.1",
    "isemail": "^2.2.1",
    "joi": "^10.6.0",
    "joi-date-extensions": "^1.0.2",
    "joi-to-json-schema": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "jquery-mapael": "^2.0.0",
    "js-base64": "^2.1.9",
    "jsonfile": "^4.0.0",
    "jsonpointer": "^4.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "~8.2.1",
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "material-ui": "^0.16.6",
    "material-ui-datatables": "^0.18.2",
    "material-ui-search-bar": "^0.4.1",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.8",
    "materialui-pagination": "0.0.6",
    "md5": "^2.1.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.3",
    "mgr-pdf-viewer-react": "^1.0.0",
    "mock-socket": "^7.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "node-ensure": "0.0.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "npm": "^5.6.0",
    "rc-collapse": "^1.7.0",
    "rc-slider": "^7.0.6",
    "rc-tooltip": "^3.4.3",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.5",
    "react-breadcrumbs": "^1.5.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.13.3",
    "react-icons": "^2.2.7",
    "react-jsonschema-form": "^1.0.0",
    "react-komposer": "^1.13.1",
    "react-masonry-component": "^4.2.2",
    "react-material-icons": "^1.0.2",
    "react-player": "^0.25.3",
    "react-prism": "^4.3.2",
    "react-pure-render": "^1.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.14.5",
    "react-stepper-horizontal": "^1.0.9",
    "react-sticky": "^5.0.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^4.8.0",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.1",
    "redux-form-material-ui": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-logic": "^0.11.6",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "reselect": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.1",
    "setimmediate": "^1.0.5",
    "shortid": "^2.2.6",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4",
    "socketio-wildcard": "^2.0.0",
    "strong-data-uri": "^1.0.4",
    "swagger-client": "^2.1.30",
    "traverse": "^0.6.6",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "url-pattern": "^1.0.3",
    "utf-8-validate": "^3.0.1",
    "uuid": "^2.0.3",
    "valid-url": "^1.0.9",
    "video-react": "^0.9.3",
    "voca": "^1.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.10.8",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "~1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^6.0.0",
    "chai-enzyme": "^0.6.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint": "^3.16.1",
    "fs-extra": "^3.0.1",
    "jsdom": "^9.8.3",
    "jsdom-global": "^2.1.0",
    "matchmedia-polyfill": "^0.3.0",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "mocha-plugin-co": "^1.0.0",
    "moxios": "^0.4.0",
    "proxyquire": "^1.7.11",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.11",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.0",
    "redux-test-utils": "^0.2.2",
    "sinon": "^1.17.6",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.10.0"
  }
}
```

`.babelsrc` has the following lines.

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Is there something that we are missing in the configurations that is causing the error?

Comment: Have you changed .babelrc file content with the updated preset value?

Comment: Sorry, that I forgot to mention the content of .babelrc. It has the following config. (I have put these lines in the original question as well).

'{
  "presets": ["env"]
}'

Comment: same issue, but got this in React Native 0.56. fxck RN, all the time save on development using RN, waste on debug RN